update statement failing with ORA-01427 - updated
I have 2 tables, see below. I need to update table1.sample1 to be the same as table2.sample2 where table1.level1=table2.level2.
enter image description here
the update I tried gives me

ORA-01427-single row subquery returns more than one row.

UPDATE table1
SET sample1 = 
   (SELECT table2.sample2
    FROM table1, table2
    WHERE table1.level1=table2.level2 and table1.sample1 is null); 


If you run the subquery stand-alone, how many rows are returned?

I'd try a correlated subqeury, without joining table1. Might work.

However, copying data between tables too often leads to inconsistency. Consider a view instead - will always be up-to-date!

You want to use a correlated sub-query:
UPDATE table1
SET sample1 = ( SELECT table2.sample2
                FROM   table2
                WHERE  table1.level1=table2.level2)
WHERE sample1 IS NULL;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table1 (sample1, level1) AS
SELECT NULL, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 800 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 900 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (sample2, level2) AS
SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL * 100 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

Then, after the update, the table contains:



SAMPLE1
LEVEL1




1
100


2
200


2
200


2
200


3
300


3
300


4
400


8
800


9
900


10
900



fiddle

If you have duplicate rows and want to update to one randomly selected row from those duplicates:
UPDATE table1
SET sample1 = ( SELECT table2.sample2
                FROM   table2
                WHERE  table1.level1=table2.level2
                AND    ROWNUM = 1)
WHERE sample1 IS NULL;


If you want the greatest of the correlated rows:
UPDATE table1
SET sample1 = ( SELECT table2.sample2
                FROM   table2
                WHERE  table1.level1=table2.level2
                ORDER BY sample2 DESC
                FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY )
WHERE sample1 IS NULL;

fiddle

Thanks Bharti for your advice. Unfortunately, I am getting the same ORA-01427 after I ran it in a real table with 100K rows.

@mspart Updated

The error you're encountering (ORA-01427) occurs because your subquery returns more than one row, and an UPDATE statement can only assign a single value to a column.
To update table1.sample1 based on the corresponding value in table2.sample2, you can use a JOIN instead of a subquery. Here’s how you can do it:
Using an update with join
 UPDATE table1 t1
SET sample1 = (
    SELECT t2.sample2
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t1.level1 = t2.level2
)
WHERE t1.sample1 IS NULL;


Are you sure Oracle supports that non-standard syntax?

i think it will work for him

It does not work. The same error 01427

the simple test case is working, but does not work on large 100K+ rows table.
